# Replace forward slash with double backslash enclosed in double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm desperately trying to replace a forward slash (`/`) with double backslash enclosed in double quotes (`"\\"`)

but

```
a=`echo "$var" | sed 's/^\///' | sed 's/\//\"\\\\\"/g'`
```

does not work, and I have no idea why. It always replaces with just one backslash and not two

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When `/` is part of a regular expression that you want to replace with the `s` (substitute) command of `sed`, you can use an other character instead of slash in the command's syntax, so you write, for example:

```
sed 's,/,\\\\,g'
```

above `,` was used instead of the usual slash to delimit two parameters of the `s` command: the regular expression describing part to be replaced and the string to be used as the replacement.

The above will replace every slash with two backslashes. A backslash is a special (quoting) character, so it must be quoted, here it's quoted with itself, that's why we need 4 backslashes to represent two backslashes.

```
$ echo /etc/passwd| sed 's,/,\\\\,g'
\\etc\\passwd
```

Answer (score 21):

How about this?

```
a=${var//\//\\\\}
```

Demo in a shell:

```
$ var=a/b/c
$ a=${var//\//\\\\}
$ echo "$a"
a\\b\\c
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize until I saw that this adding a second forward slash at the start of the replacement makes makes it global. Very useful!

Comment: busybox ash(BusyBox v1.21.1,v1.22.1) has a trouble with '/' substitution 
$ a=abc/abc/abc
$ echo ${a//c/_}
ab_/ab_/ab_
$ echo ${a//\//_}
abc/abc/abc

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it: `tr '/' '\'`

```
$ var=a/b/c
$ echo "$var"
a/b/c
$ tr '/' '\' <<< "$var"
a\b\c
```