# How to use difftool and mergetool on Windows 10 Ubuntu bash (WSL)

Tags: windows, bash, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, p4merge

I use Windows 10 Ubuntu bash, provided by Windows Subsystem for Linux. I want to use a visual diff/merge tool for git. I installed [p4merge](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-apps/merge-diff-tool-p4merge) on Windows (followed this [artice](https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/git-for-window-tip-use-p4merge-as-mergetool/)) and configured the git `.gitconfig` file with the following way (I adjusted the paths to be accessible from Windows 10 Ubuntu bash):

```
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = /mnt/c/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[difftool "p4merge"]
    path = /mnt/c/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

Additionally, I added the following folder to the bash `PATH` variable in `.bashrc` to make it callable from anywhere:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Program Files/Perforce"
```

So my problem is that if I call `git difftool` in the bash - to investigate the changes with `p4merge` - I got the following messages

- in bash: `Unable to translate current working directory. Using C:\Windows\system32`.
- the `p4merge` application is started right after the call but gives the following message: `Error: ... point to an invalid file`.

If I understand right, this problem may emanate from the fact that a Windows program (namely `p4merge`) could not find a file that is referenced with a Linux file path (e.g. `/mnt/c/..`).

Is there any way to solve this kind of problem? (Maybe it is a more general problem: using Linux path from Windows application.)

Anyway, I do not insist on using `p4merge` but any similar visual tool to compare differences and to make merge possible.

Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create file `p4mergebash.sh` and set `$PATH`:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/bin
touch ~/bin/p4mergebash.sh
chmod +x ~/bin/p4mergebash.sh
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Perforce' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

`p4mergebash.sh` content:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

LOCAL="$1"
REMOTE="$2"

case "$LOCAL"
in
    *)
    L=$(echo "C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/lxss/rootfs${LOCAL}" | sed 's,/,\\\\,g')
    ;;
esac

case "$REMOTE"
in
    *)
    R=$(echo `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/"$REMOTE" | sed 's,/mnt/c/,C:/,g' | sed 's,/,\\\\,g')
    ;;
esac

echo "$L"
echo "$R"
p4merge.exe "$L" "$R"
```

Above script assumes your `AppData` and your git repo are on `C:` drive. Insert your username into the angle brackets (i.e. `<username>`).

**Note**: Ensure there are no `CRLF`'s in `p4mergebash.sh`.

Then set git config:

```bash
git config --global diff.tool p4mergebash
git config --global difftool.p4mergebash.cmd '~/bin/p4mergebash.sh $LOCAL $REMOTE'
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

- [how to make git difftool to always export absolute paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397845/how-to-make-git-difftool-to-always-export-absolute-paths)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice
- [Replace forward slash with double backslash enclosed in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379293/replace-forward-slash-with-double-backslash-enclosed-in-double-quotes)
- https://gist.github.com/rcapraro/aad8a8c3ad96fe563fce

Comment: Worked very well for me. (Using meld)  In my case however, I had to slightly change the contents of p4mergebash.sh to make it match the LOCAL so that it would fetch from my tmp directory for remote as well.  R=$(echo "C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/lxss/rootfs${REMOTE}" | sed 's,/,\\\\,g')

Comment: @rofrol  `L=$(echo "C:/Users/ysuh/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc/LocalState/rootfs${LOCAL}" | sed 's,/,\\\\,g')`

I had to update the bash script's value for L.

`/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe "$L" "$R"`

I also had to hardcode the executable path.  I couldn't get it to work with just updating the PATH via .bash_profile.

Answer (score 23):

## Solution to this problem is simplified!

Thanks to the [Windows 10 version 1903](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/) update, accessing the Linux subsystem from Windows 10 is now possible. It is much more easier.

Just make sure that **git config --global --list** has these lines. That's all!

```
diff.tool=p4merge
merge.tool=p4merge
difftool.p4merge.cmd=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe "$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)" "$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)"
mergetool.p4merge.cmd=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe "$(wslpath -aw $BASE)" "$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)" "$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)" "$(wslpath -aw $MERGED)"
mergetool.p4merge.trustexitcode=false
```

#### Takeaways:

- Linux subsystem now resides at **\\wsl$\{distro name}\** path.
- Which means you can access the **tmp folder** at **\\wsl$\Ubuntu\tmp\**. Even from the File Explorer!
- **wslpath -aw** command does the heavy lifting for you.
- The command now properly translates Linux relative **/tmp/whatever** path to a Windows 10 relative path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. The only addition is that you most probably want to use `wslpath -am` to convert `\ ` to `/`

Comment: In my experience, it didn't need -am. But defiantly, you can add it just in case. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I've added the flag to force the unix line ending on p4merge `p4merge.exe -le unix`. If not it kept changing the line endings.

Comment: Note that if you happen to use WinMerge, the last parameter (with `$MERGED`) needs the `/o` flag for the saving to work correctly.

Answer (score 9):

For `Beyond Compare 4`, add these lines to your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[merge]
    tool = BeyondCompare4
    guitool = BeyondCompare4
[diff]
    guitool = beyondcompare4
[difftool "beyondcompare4"]
    cmd = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Beyond\\ Compare\\ 4/bcomp.exe "$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)" "$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)"
[mergetool "BeyondCompare4"]
    cmd = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Beyond\\ Compare\\ 4/bcomp.exe "$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)" "$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)" "$(wslpath -aw $BASE)" "$(wslpath -aw $MERGED)"
```

Comment: I had to add the `tool = beyondcompare4` line under `[diff]`, otherwise when I entered `git difftool HEAD^!` it opened the merge window. And `guitool` isn't really needed, `tool` is enough. Other than that, it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica no problem. Thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the .gitconfig lines I use for p4merge for merge and diff tool. Also to use VS code as commit message editor:

```
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[difftool "p4merge"]
    cmd = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe \"$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)\"
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    cmd = /mnt/c/Program\\ Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe -le unix \"$(wslpath -aw $BASE)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $LOCAL)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $REMOTE)\" \"$(wslpath -aw $MERGED)\"
    trustexitcode = false
    keepBackup = false
[core]
    editor = code -w
```

I like BeyondCompare better for 3-way merge, but [p4merge](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core-apps/merge-diff-tool-p4merge) is the best free option in my opinion.
To get VS Code working with wsl, see this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode).